# Configuring database to connect 21c XE with primavera p6

Tags: java, database, oracle, primavera

I trying to connect primavera p6 to express edition 21c

1- XE db had been installed

2- started to configre db using "dbsetup" script

3- I got an error which show in the below image

[image]

Please if anyone have any help kindly share with me

Comment: What did you discover when you googled "ORA-65096"?

Comment: I searched for this error but I'm not developer i couldn't find a direct solution, all talking about creating users using command line , in my case i'm using the script file provided in the primavera p6

Comment: It still comes down to the actual SQL 'CREATE USER' statement, and the oracle user issuing the statement, and the database (container or pdb) it is being issued in.  The database doesn't care if it comes from Primavera, sqlplus, SQL Dev, Toad, or a connected Tardis.

Comment: I tried this command but still get the error ""alter system set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true SCOPE=SPFILE;""

Comment: Hidden parameters (those that begin with an underscore) are hidden (undocumented) for a reason. Shouldn't be used outside of the direction of oracle support.  You didn't answer any questions that I raised.  Connected to a container or a pdb? What Oracle user is issuing the command?  What was the actual, full, complete, exact CREATE USER command?

Answer (score 2):

When you configure a tool to setup some objects/users/etc in the database, it is going to ask you for database connection settings.

For XE, we have what is called a "multi-tenant" configuration, which means there is a "root" or "container" database that is generally not for use by end users, and one or more "pluggable" databases, into which you would configure your users etc.

The root database is called XE and the pluggable database is called XEPDB1, unless you didnt use the defaults.

Thus for Primavera you should nominate XEPDB1 as the database to install into. If you choose to install in "XE", then since this is the container database, there are rules as to what the users must be named, which is why you're getting this error.  Switch to installing into the pluggable database and you should have more success.